# Viber не видит Open Graph разметку

Tags: html, html5, viber, opengraph

Есть сайт, когда ссылку на страницу сайта кидаю, например, в skype, то с сайта подтягивается картинка, тайтл и описание, которые находятся в мета-тегах og:title, og:description, og:image. Но когда кидаю ссылку в Viber, то указанная выше информация не подтягивается. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться что не так.

```
<meta property="og:locale" content="ru_RU" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Кулиничи (Лосево-1) - ROOMIO" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Мы создали максимально комфортное место, в котором людям будет приятно находиться во время ожидания. Для создания такой атмосферы мы использовали стабилизированный мох, ведь он абсолютно безвреден для людей и обладает гипоаллергенными качествами." />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://roomio.com.ua/projects/losevo-1/" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="ROOMIO" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://roomio.com.ua/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/1-2.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://roomio.com.ua/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/1-2.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1349" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="900" />
```

Comment: Viber должен выводить open graph. У меня как-то была такая же проблема, решилась тем что через некоторое время все стало отображаться (в течение часа-двух). Попробуйте проверить как будет отображаться линка на сайт в дhугом Viber куда вы ранее не бросали линку на этот сайт

Comment: Viber может кэшировать предедущие данные по линке и выводить старые результаты